# Leiningen java-agents not working in uberjar

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, javaagents

In my Leiningen project I have the following config:

```
:java-agents [[com.newrelic.agent.java/newrelic-agent "3.19.2"]]
```

When running my app as in `lein repl` the agent is being run, but when I create the uberjar and run it like:

```
java -jar target/proclodo-spa-server-rendering.jar
```

the agent is not started. I could include newrelic-agent.jar in my uberjar and pass the -javaagent argument, but I'm trying to avoid having big binary blobs in my repository that will not be upgraded automatically (why does New Relic even recommend that?). I tried adding:

```
:bootclasspath true
```

due to this comment:

```
;; Java agents can instrument and intercept certain VM features. Include
;; :bootclasspath true to place the agent jar on the bootstrap classpath.
```

but it made no difference. How is the agent jar supposed to be placed in the CLASSPATH so I can verify it's working?

I am using Jetty, which is said to interfere with `bootclasspath`, but I'm not sure how it should be interfering. Everything seems to run fine, it's only the agent that's not starting.

Answer (score 0):

If you run java yourself, you have to pass the VM options, such as the debugging agent to use, yourself. lein can't package that into a jar: there is simply no mechanism for doing it.

Comment: What does :bootclasspath do then? The jar doesn't seem to be inside my uberjar. How do I pass the argument without having the jar in my repo? which is bad

Comment: @Pablo Those are really two new questions, not followups on this one. But, briefly: once you use leiningen to build a jar, you have a jar just like any other java-based jar, and you can look up how to set an agent when running a jar; it's no longer clojure-specific. If you want an agent to be used in your deployment environment, you need to arrange to have the agent jar exist there, and you need to arrange for the java-agent argument to be passed as well.

Comment: For example, since you use newrelic, https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/java-agent-manual-installation seems to be a quite thorough explanation of how to use it when running a jar.

Comment: From the Leiningen documentation, it says that :bootclasspath set to true should place the agent jar on the classpath, am I reading it wrong? You are saying this has to be done manually. Is the Leiningen documentation wrong?

Comment: I read that newrelic documentation, it recommends putting a jar in your version control tree, which is horrible. It's a big binary file instead of source code and by just being copied there is out of my build system, so it won't get updated unless I explicitly remember to check for updates.